# Can Jetty hot redeployment work without service interruption?

Tags: jetty, hotdeploy, jetty-9

I'm running a web app with Jetty 9.0.5 (I could update, 9.1.2 is the latest as I write this). I have the usual web app deployer as described in the [Jetty docs](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/hot-deployment.html) and defined in `etc/jetty-deploy.xml`.  I use a Jetty xml file to define my web app context, so when I push new code to my production server, I upload a new `myapp.war` file using `rsync` and then touch that `myapp.xml` file.  This works pretty well, but there are few seconds where the app throws a `NullPointerException` or other weirdness, and some users appear to be getting corrupt statically served files (`.js` files from the war), so that they have to flush their browser's cache for the app to work again.

Is this supposed to work perfectly, or do you expect a brief dead period like this?

I don't put the `myapp.war` in the `webapps` directory (only the the `myapp.xml` is there) and `explodeWars` is `true` in the deployer.